# I want to draw using canvas over an existing xml background how can I do it?

Tags: android

This is the class where i draw the picture onto this canvas, and on this class I’m trying to set the canvas's background to an existing xml layout that I designed.
The idea of what I want to do is like this made-up function: canvas.setBackground(R.layout.game); on the onDraw method.
The java class:

```
package com.example.snakesnladders;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;

public class MyBringBack extends View {
    Bitmap playerW;

    public MyBringBack(Context context) {
        super(context);

        playerW = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.white);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(playerW, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/easymap"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/whitePlayer"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blackPlayer"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btRoll"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cubePic"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:text="Roll"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cubePic"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cube" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTurn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cubePic"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btRoll"
        android:text="Your turn!"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: quick and dirty: Insert the the `MyBringBack` view in your xml and set height and width to `match_parent` as last element with a transparent Background

Comment: It’s not making sense to me, where exactly should I insert the MyBringBack view in the XML file, can you write for me please?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: I’ve tried to use what you wrote but it didn’t work so I recreated the picture to fit the whole screen, and used it as my background, although now my problem is setting up the button to react to clicks(because the background is a picture I can’t set the button like I did before from the XML file

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty: Insert the the MyBringBack view in your xml and set height and width to match_parent as last element with a transparent Background

Upüdate your MyBringBack with these constructors:

```
public MyBringBack (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initView();
}

public MyBringBack (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

public MyBringBack (Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    //DO WHAT YOU WANT ON INIT
    playerW = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.white);

}
```

And XML Like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/easymap"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/whitePlayer"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/white"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/blackPlayer"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@drawable/black" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btRoll"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cubePic"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:text="Roll"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cubePic"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cube" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTurn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cubePic"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btRoll"
    android:text="Your turn!"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

  <your.package.MyBringBack
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_bring_back"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort unfortunately it's not working. The error is “Custom view MyBringBack is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work”

Comment: So you have to use the other constructors